# Using Camera in the Android emulator

Tags: android, camera, emulation, simulation

I wish to simulate camera in the android emulator using the webcam. Basically I need to only take photos with the camera in the emulator (live preview is not needed i.e if it makes it any easier)

I followed the tutorial [here](http://www.tomgibara.com/android/camera-source) which is the only one I could find that was close to my requirements

But many of the libraries used in that tutorial(like android.hardware.CameraDevice) are not available in present sdk and are replaced by new libraries(like android.hardware.camera).

Any help on how to do this in the present sdk(2.1 or 2.2) would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think this answer help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/71319601/4797289

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update: ICS emulator supports camera.

Comment: Taking pictures work (with an intent), but no live preview (the Camera.open() doesn't work).

Answer (score 148):

In your AVD advanced settings, you should be able to set front and back cameras to `Webcam()` or `Emulated`.

[image]

Comment: Don't forget, Front and Back camera can't be the same.

Comment: After clicking "advanced", I had to scroll down to find these UI elements, they were hidden.

Comment: There are two "advanced settings". Not the one after the emulator is running. in Device Manager, click the pencil next to the device, Show Advanced Settings.

Answer (score 5):

Some elaboration, in the hope of clarifying what has already been said:

As stated above, **Webcams are supported natively** in the current SDK, but only on recent android versions (4.0 and higher)

Webcam detection is automatic where present. In 4.0.3, the camera defaults to the front-facing camera so a lot of applications (especially pre-2.3 applications, which can only fetch the default camera, i.e. the back-facing one) will still show you the old checkerbox-with-moving-square stand-in instead.

I think some more info is available in the following post: [Camera on Android Eclipse emulator:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284583/camera-on-android-eclipse-emulator/8443673#8443673)

Or at least, that's the most information I've been able to find--aside from the brief, uninformative statements in the release notes for the SDK tools.

Answer (score 4):

If you're working with **command-line tools** or just want to edit your `config.ini` file directly, you have options:

### Option 1: use command-line options

```sh
emulator -help | grep cam # => shows items such as -camera-back
emulator -help-camera-back # => show supported values for this option
emulator -avd $MY_AVD -camera-back virtualscene # Example invocation
```

If you want to use your actual camera instead of a mock, the option's value will be `webcam${N}`. How do you know what `${N}` should be? `emulator -webcam-list` lists and describes the cameras available on your computer.

### Option 2: edit the config file

Using the legal values we learnt above, edit the file `~/.android/avd/${MY_AVD}/config.ini` and add a line (I'll use `virtualscene` as my value of choice):

```
hw.camera.back = virtualscene
```

Answer (score 2):

Update of @param's answer.

**ICS emulator supports camera.**

I found [Simple Android Photo Capture](http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/simple-android-photo-capture/), which supports webcam in android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Does not seem like it, but android recognises a webcam as a device. Every time I run the emulator my webcam's active light comes on.

Answer (score 0):

There is [an updated version of Tom Gibara's tutorial](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/09/live-camera-preview-in-android-emulator.html). You can change the Webcam Broadcaster to [work with JMyron instead of the old JMF](http://www.ecole.ensicaen.fr/~reynaud/android/webcam_in_android_emulator.html).

The new emulator (sdk r15) manage webcams ; but it has some problems with integrated webcams (at least with mine's ^^)

Answer (score 0):

The newest camera2 apis work fine w/ an emulator that has camera support enabled.

Example for using the newer API:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/AutoFitTextureView.java

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you just need to show a picture in response to a camera request, there is [image-to-camera](https://github.com/GhostFlying/image-to-camera).

Just download, build, install, copy an image of your choice to the device, and you can select it via the app, which is an alternative to the built-in camera.