# camera activity dies on emulator and force closes

Tags: android, android-activity, camera, forceclose

I have an application which captures images but whenever I click button to start camera activity it force closes and below is the log cat i get. I have been stuck here for long and getting no direction to proceed forward.Any help would be appreciated a lot.

LOG CAT

```
 07-04 15:08:08.803: I/System.out(757): kkkkkkkkkkkk
 07-04 15:08:09.053: I/WindowManager(93): createSurface Window{416b4db8 comp.com/comp.com.receipt paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
 07-04 15:08:09.133: D/dalvikvm(146): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 339K, 36% free 10622K/16455K, paused 164ms
 07-04 15:08:09.842: W/WindowManager(93): Window freeze timeout expired.
 07-04 15:08:09.842: W/WindowManager(93): Force clearing orientation change: Window{416b4db8 comp.com/comp.com.receipt paused=false}
 07-04 15:08:09.922: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(93): setKernelCountSet(10006, 0) failed with errno -2
 07-04 15:08:09.922: I/ActivityManager(93): No longer want com.android.deskclock (pid 358): hidden #16
 07-04 15:08:11.153: D/dalvikvm(146): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 371K, 36% free 10612K/16455K, paused 68ms
 07-04 15:08:11.363: I/Process(772): Sending signal. PID: 772 SIG: 9
 07-04 15:08:11.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(37): disableMessage: msg_type = 0xffff
 07-04 15:08:11.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(37):     CAMERA_MSG_ERROR
 07-04 15:08:11.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(37):     CAMERA_MSG_SHUTTER
 07-04 15:08:11.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(37):     CAMERA_MSG_FOCUS
 07-04 15:08:11.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(37):     CAMERA_MSG_ZOOM
 07-04 15:08:11.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(37):     CAMERA_MSG_PREVIEW_FRAME
 07-04 15:08:11.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(37):     CAMERA_MSG_VIDEO_FRAME
 07-04 15:08:11.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(37):     CAMERA_MSG_POSTVIEW_FRAME
 07-04 15:08:11.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(37):     CAMERA_MSG_RAW_IMAGE
 07-04 15:08:11.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(37):     CAMERA_MSG_COMPRESSED_IMAGE
 07-04 15:08:11.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(37):     CAMERA_MSG_RAW_IMAGE_NOTIFY
 07-04 15:08:11.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(37):     CAMERA_MSG_PREVIEW_METADATA
 07-04 15:08:11.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(37): **** Currently enabled messages:
 07-04 15:08:11.403: V/EmulatedCamera_Camera(37): doStopPreview
 07-04 15:08:11.403: V/EmulatedCamera_Camera(37): cancelPicture
 07-04 15:08:11.403: V/EmulatedCamera_Camera(37): releaseCamera
 07-04 15:08:11.403: V/EmulatedCamera_Camera(37): doStopPreview
 07-04 15:08:11.403: V/EmulatedCamera_FakeDevice(37): disconnectDevice
 07-04 15:08:11.403: I/CameraService(37): Destroying camera 1
 07-04 15:08:11.403: V/EmulatedCamera_Camera(37): closeCamera
 07-04 15:08:11.403: V/EmulatedCamera_Camera(37): doStopPreview
 07-04 15:08:11.413: I/ActivityManager(93): Process com.android.camera (pid 772) has died.
 07-04 15:08:11.443: W/AudioFlinger(37): session id 5 not found for pid 37
 07-04 15:08:11.453: W/AudioFlinger(37): session id 6 not found for pid 37
 07-04 15:08:11.583: D/dalvikvm(483): GC_CONCURRENT freed 295K, 4% free 10017K/10375K, paused 7ms+7ms
 07-04 15:08:12.573: D/dalvikvm(93): GC_EXPLICIT freed 495K, 11% free 12770K/14215K, paused 7ms+14ms
 07-04 15:08:19.922: W/ActivityManager(93): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{4159c1c0 com.android.camera/.Camera}
 07-04 15:09:37.513: W/ThrottleService(93): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
 07-04 15:10:31.653: D/Smack(216): [SSLXMPPConnection@1094112608] create socket connection(mtalk.google.com, 5228)
 07-04 15:10:31.684: W/GTalkService(216): [AndroidEndpoint@1094054264] doConnect: caught XMPPError connecting to mtalk.google.com:5228.: (502)
 07-04 15:10:31.684: W/GTalkService(216):   -- caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to mtalk.google.com/74.125.127.188 (port 5228): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
 07-04 15:10:31.693: E/GTalkService(216): connectionClosed: no XMPPConnection - That's strange!
 07-04 15:10:34.714: D/ConnectivityService(93): handleInetConditionHoldEnd: net=0, condition=0, published condition=0
 07-04 15:13:47.923: D/dalvikvm(174): GC_CONCURRENT freed 387K, 6% free 10358K/10951K, paused 5ms+6ms
 07-04 15:15:31.772: D/Smack(216): [SSLXMPPConnection@1094557096] create socket connection(mtalk.google.com, 5228)
 07-04 15:15:31.783: W/GTalkService(216): [AndroidEndpoint@1094054264] doConnect: caught XMPPError connecting to mtalk.google.com:5228.: (502)
 07-04 15:15:31.783: W/GTalkService(216):   -- caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to mtalk.google.com/74.125.127.188 (port 5228): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
 07-04 15:15:31.792: E/GTalkService(216): connectionClosed: no XMPPConnection - That's strange!
```

Comment: i prefer to test your app on real device, not emulator.

Comment: I think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284583/camera-on-android-eclipse-emulator

Comment: but on emulator also it should work.. right ?

Comment: no, it wont work normally...but i read some where, we can achieve this..just check on internet