# Android Camera facing front not working in emulator

Tags: android-emulator, camera

I am developing android application. To run my application I created emulator with the following configuration settings(I want to set webcam as front camera).

**Configures Camera facing front : webcam0,
Device Ram Size: 512,
...
...**

But when I checked if front camera available,

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
frontCam = pm.hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.camera.front");
rearCam = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
```

I am getting **frontCam** value as **false** and **rearCam** value as **true**.

AVD screenshot is given below. How can I use webcam as front camera?

[image: AVD Configuration]

Comment: Does `adb logcat` reveal any errors? I suspect this could be a problem with connecting to the webcam. What kind of webcam are you using and how is it connected to your computer? Also, does the webcam work with other software like Skype?

Comment: adb logcat didn't give any errors. I am using Logitech camera. It opens as a back camera. (i.e)VideoCapture mCamera = new VideoCapture(Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID); If I open as front camera (VideoCapture mCamera = new VideoCapture(Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID+1)), it is not open.

Comment: Do you have it specified as both the front and back camera? I don't think that it supported. It needs to be either the front or the back.

Comment: No. I declared only as "Configures Camera facing front : webcam0". But it takes as back camera.

Answer (score 2):

have you Configured your AVD to **Configures Camera Facing Front**

if not then Edit your AVD OR Create new

[image: Edit your AVD]

Add Configures Camera Facing Front

[image: Click New in hardware Section]

Set your Desired option

[image: Set your Desired option]

And Run your project.

Hope this Helps.

Happy coding. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I already set "Configures Camera facing front : webcam0". Even after I set this it is not working.

Comment: same case with me...camera not starting