# Android Emulator - /dev/video missing

Tags: android, android-camera

I am creating an application that connects to the phone camera from native code.
This works great on my phone.
The problem is that when i try to do the same thing with android emulator, there is
no "/dev/video" to connect to (i know the camera is connected because i am able to open it
using the camera app).
Does anyone know if there is another way i can connect to the camera from native code?

Answer (score 0):

**/dev/video0** is, in terms of Android, an *implementation detail*, and not guaranteed to be present on any device or emulator.

Emulator support for camera is very limited, see for example [Android webcam enable in emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857006/android-webcam-enable-in-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

There is no official native camera API on Android, so there's no guaranteed to work way of doing this.

For maximum compatibility, use the Java API and send the image data to native code for processing, if necessary.

Comment: even this is very limited on the emulator