# getting wrong pictures from android studio’s emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I managed to connect my webcam to android studio's emulator, however I am keep getting these wrong preview from the camera.Does anybody know the possible cause of it?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Try picking the hardware camera in emulator settings. You should have 3 options - none, emulated and device

Comment: I've all tried, still not working...

Comment: try giving more memory to emulator and install/update intel HAXM. if not already.

Comment: I'm just a beginner of Android studio, can you tell me how to get more memory and uptade HAXM?

Comment: you can check this question for help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857006/android-webcam-enable-in-emulator  Btw, I suggest you using real phone to test your camera app.

Answer (score 0):

May be following will work for you

1.Open AVD Manager:

2.Add/Edit AVD:

3.Click Advanced Settings in the bottom of the screen:

**4. Set your camera of choice as the front/back cameras:**

[image: Camera]

hope it will help you..

**UPDATE**

[image: Camera2]

try with delete the old AVD and create fresh one with these configs.