# Android camera in desktop emulator

Tags: android, camera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use web camera in android emulator to capture a live image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276450/how-to-use-web-camera-in-android-emulator-to-capture-a-live-image)

Is it possible to use the camera of emulator of android sdk through the web cam?

Answer (score 0):

This question asks the same thing: [Camera on Android Eclipse emulator:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284583/camera-on-android-eclipse-emulator)

The answer on there suggests that since Android 4.0, the emulator supports using your webcam as the emulator's camera. SDK Tools revision 14.