# Not able to start emulator's front camera via web cam showing error.!

Tags: android, android-widget

while click on 'camera' icon in emulator the dialog box appears and then i click ok, its shows error:- "Unfortunately, Camera has Stop".

[Find out snapshots here..!](https://picasaweb.google.com/114026936707194331750/February212013?authkey=Gv1sRgCK3EyMO6qeGzZg)

Comment: Which android emulator you are using? Also while making avd configure the front camera to the webcam.Use Android avd 4.0.

Comment: @curious M using emulator 4.2 version, Device: Galaxy Nexus, CPU/ABI: Intel Atom x86, and have enabled camera option in avd configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of android are you running in the emulator? Anything above 4.0 allows you to use the webcam as camera for the emulator. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284583/camera-on-android-eclipse-emulator/8443673#8443673) post for more details.

Comment: I am able to use camera of web cam in my emulator but only once a time...again when i run my app it say : **Unfortunately camera is stopped**  So every time i created new AVD its work well for first time and then shows error.... m using 4.2 (17) platform version.

Comment: it seems that problem is there in your application..How about this, try the native camera application and see if it works for more than 1 time..if it works fine then i think problem lies in your code...if doesn't we have to see about it...can u check that