# How can we directly access webcam from Android emulator

Tags: android

I have been developing an application which needs to access video camera but with Android emulator i couldn't find a way to access my web cam directly as the Android device's camera. so any way to do this ?

Thanks !!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer here is no, but I could be wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Camera in the Android emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884620/using-camera-in-the-android-emulator) see also [How to use web camera in android emulator to capture a live image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276450/how-to-use-web-camera-in-android-emulator-to-capture-a-live-image)

Comment: @Brian: You are not wrong. I'd use a real device for camera-related apps anyway, the emulator would be too slow.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible full stop.

Use a real device if you want to test recording video with your app.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but I had to find a solution. I saw [Tom Gibara's solution](http://www.tomgibara.com/android/camera-source) and [the Neil Davies' updated version](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/09/live-camera-preview-in-android-emulator.html) but both worked with JMF which is quite obsolete ... and doesn't work with my Integrated Webcam.
So I had to change some code and use the JMyron library for the Webcam Broadcaster.

But be aware that, like everybody said, there is no direct access. There are just some tricks to bypass the problem.