# Android Emulator + Web Cam

Tags: android, android-camera

Is there a way to emulate Android Emulator to use the webcam of the laptop ? or is there any alternative ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Camera in the Android emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884620/using-camera-in-the-android-emulator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this question here at stackoverflow: [How to use web camera in android emulator to capture a live image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276450/how-to-use-web-camera-in-android-emulator-to-capture-a-live-image)