# why Can't activate the camera in the android simulator?

Tags: android

I wrote simple application that using the cell phone camera.

When i trying to load the simulator ( AVD ) i can't see the camera on the simulator. 
My webCam is active and work fine without the simulator - and i need to activate it also in the simulator for using the debug option. 
When i install the application on my cell phone - the camera is started as i expected. But i need to debug on the simulator. 
What i need to check ? How to activate and see the taken picture on the simulator ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the questions in stackoverflow:

- [Using Camera in the Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884620/using-camera-in-the-android-emulator)
- [How to use web camera in android emulator to capture a live image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276450/how-to-use-web-camera-in-android-emulator-to-capture-a-live-image)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can use external camera in emulator, but as i have experienced with Android emulator's camera, it has problems like sometimes it doesn't work and sometimes works if camera in the emulator works. You can see pictures taken in DDMS perspective top right corner in Eclipse and there you will see SD card/DCM/Camera/ also note that camera facility should be enabled in your emulator by AVR, and also SD Card support.