# Android Emulator Settings

Tags: android, emulation

I've been programming Droids for about 7 months and as much as I enjoy certain features, the majority of time seems to be spent getting the Emulator working correctly...

No matter what type of AVD I create, the camera will not work, video won't play, and I just found out Google Maps will not work either.  I've targeted 2.2 to 4.0 with no success.

Has anyone had similar issues?  Has anyone found a resource that explains basic settings needed for these things to work in the Emulator?

Comment: If you want to work with Google Maps you need to set the emulator target to use the `Google APIs` not `Android`: https://developers.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/installing

Answer (score 0):

1. Google Maps work on emulator you may not have used the Google API
2. Concerning playing Video, Android Emulator supports H.263 encoding and decoding, H.264 AVC and MPEG-4 SP both only decoding, Its  true that the ability to handle video playback is very limited that's why i advice you to use an actual Android device

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the camera on the emulator. [Using Camera in the Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884620/using-camera-in-the-android-emulator)

I found something interesting here though: [Live Camera Previews in Android](http://www.tomgibara.com/android/camera-source)

Do not use the emulator for testing video playback. Its ability to handle video playback is very limited. Use an actual Android device.

Answer (score 0):

Camera support via webcam is now included (as of Jun 28, 2012) with the latest developer tools. There are lots of other nice additions as well (sensors input via tethered device, etc.).  Details here: [Google I/O 2012 - What's New in Android Developers' Tools](http://youtu.be/Erd2k6EKxCQ)