# How to use Computer Camera in Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, camera

I want to use my laptop camera in the Android Emulator, but the app crashes when I try to do so. Moreover, the emulator itself can't use the camera. Is there any software or SDK version that supports webcams. Currently I am using the Android Froyo 2.2 SDK.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried that yet, although it sounds rather useful. You might wann check this

[How to use web camera in android emulator to capture a live image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276450/how-to-use-web-camera-in-android-emulator-to-capture-a-live-image)

and

[Using Camera in the Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884620/using-camera-in-the-android-emulator)

One answer says, this is only supported in the emulator starting with android ICS (4.0), but no further information is provided, so you might want to invest a little more research on this version.

Comment: So If I upgrade the emulator to ICS. Will I be able to run my apps written for froyo on ICS..

Comment: @AlfredJames Yes. Programs of a lower api level should run on a higher api level, but not vice versa.