# Android emulator settings no camera option (for virtual scene)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I want my android emulator to be in a virtual scene when I open the camera but it doesn't work. It just shows a pixelated face instead. Also, the camera option doesn't seem to exist in emulator settings. I checked all the required versions for both android studio and android emulator but still, I don't have the setting and the virtual scene.
[image]

[image]

Comment: use this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/71319601/4797289

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you create a new Android Virtual Device (AVD) and in my case I used one with Play Store support.

In the Verify Configuration screen, click on [Advanced Options] and you should see:

[image: Verify Configuration Screen]

And make sure that Camera Back is set to 'VirtualScene'.

As documented in [Step 5 of ARCore - Create a virtual device with AR support](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/emulator#create_avd)

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find this answer from anywhere else.