# Android Studio camera shows pixelated face instead of virtual scene

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera2

I'm developing an app that uses the android.hardware.camera2 API to display a real-time camera image on the screen.  Everything worked as expected until I updated Android Studio to version 4.1.1.  Now, instead of showing the "dining room" virtual scene, it shows this weird pixelated face thing.

[image: Image of android studio camera pixelated face]

The weird face (or whatever it is) is also bobbing up and down.
This is an image of the project component tree:

[image: project GUI hierarchy]

This image is nowhere in my project, which is fairly simple anyway.  In no way did I program this image into the app.  It should be displaying the virtual scene instead.  Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

I can confirm that updating Android Studio is causing this problem for others as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android emulator settings no camera option (for virtual scene)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64724772/android-emulator-settings-no-camera-option-for-virtual-scene) Create a new AVD and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Yes, that did solve the problem.