# Need help navigating the virtual scene programmatically on emulator

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator, android-uiautomator

I am trying to create automated tests for our app using UIAutomator. Part of our tests involves scanning multiple QR codes. I found a way to load a the QR code images to the virtual scene using this solution: [Android emulator camera custom image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818389/android-emulator-camera-custom-image/64922184#64922184)

However, I need to navigate the inside the scene in order to scan the intended QR code. Manually, I can navigate by holding option + WASD or option + mouse movement but I wish to do in automatically using code.

[image: virtual scene image]

I have tried looking into work arounds like sending keystrokes for the mentioned keys above, or manipulating the x,y,z rotation coordinates of the emulator to move the view, but to no avail.

Comment: You should be able to adjust the x,y and z position in your Toren1BD.posters. They tell the Android emulator where the image should be displayed.