# A way to switch camera source to another video source in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, tcp, camera, video-streaming

Are there way to change default camera video source in Android to another?
I want to transfer video stream from PC using TCP(or UDP... etc) and Sockets/WebSockets to Android device, and I need a way to show that in any app on device that uses camera.

I have checked some Internet resources but I just found few camera Api's that are useful for creating custom camera app, but they don't solve my problem.

Comment: While Android does have support for [External USB cameras](https://source.android.com/docs/core/camera/external-usb-cameras) that needs to built into the ROM. If you are referring to overriding the Camera/Camera2 APIs that isn't possible on stock consumer devices. See: [Android emulator camera custom image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13818389/295004) for testing with emulator.