# Android Emulator crashes and quits when opening camera

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I read somewhere to use the following command to start my Android Emulator so I can use my Macbook's camera to take pictures and record videos instead of seeing the default pixelated camera preview.

```
sudo ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_4_API_34
```

The Emulator starts successfully. The issue now is that once I try to open the camera, the emulator crashes and quits immediately.

On looking at the logs in the terminal I could see something like the following error message:

```
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  sudo ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_4_API_34
```

I'm not sure what the above means, but any ideas to resolve this will be really appreciated.

Comment: Unclear if you've seen: [Android emulator camera custom image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71319601/295004) and specifically this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73299846/295004