# How to inject a QR code image for end-to-end testing a QR code scanning app

Tags: android, ios, automated-tests, ui-automation

End-to-end testing an app with QR-code scanning features seems to be difficult. Is there a way to kind of inject a QR code image into an Android device or simulator to automate this scanning process? I'd ideally like to have a solution that doesn't require access to the source code of the app.

I am looking for a solution for iOS and Android

Comment: You can insert images into the virtual scene of the android studio camera. This answer outlines it -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818389/android-emulator-camera-custom-image and the example is of a qr code as well but it is geared towards the emulated device and not a physical one

Comment: Thanks @KaranShishoo. What about iOS?