# Emulator Camera is not working properly

Tags: android-emulator

I want to use the camera in one of my projects. So I'm using the camera of my emulator device but the problem is when the camera is on its show's some weird animation i.e a box is moving all over the screen. What is the solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: I got  the solution. Now I'm using Genymotion which satisfy my need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem. This is the default behavior of the Emulator's Camera.
I suggest using any real device to achieve this since there is no way to "simulate camera in the Android emulator using the webcam" except by extensively modifying the Android firmware.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884620/using-camera-in-the-android-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Emulator camera cannot be used if there is no access to webcam. I have downloaded `GenyMotion` emulator which solved my problem.
Thank you for your support.