# Camera app in Android Virtual Device is not showing

Tags: android, android-camera, android-virtual-device

I have created AVD with latest Android Pie and Android Oreo as well. But the camera app is not showing as you can see in the screenshots. [image]

I have created 3 AVDs. The one without play store has camera app but others don not. 
[image]

Comment: Aye, here ya go, mate. [how to configure camera settings while setting up an AVD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37390717/5990846).

Comment: I changed the settings in existing AVDs and restarted but no effect. Created a new one with front cam emulated and back scene view. Now the camera app is showing. But when I changed to webcam it has stopped working. Is there something wrong with my PC?